How to get the GCP Organization Id from the organization's domain name in Python
I want to get the Organization Id based on the organizations display name (or domain name)
Fairly easy with gcloud but I want to use Python to link with other python modules.

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient import discovery

def get_org_id_from_name(credentials, organization_name):
  """Retrieves the organization ID based on the provided organization name.

  Args:
      credentials: The Google Cloud authentication credentials object.
      organization_name: The name of the organization to search for.

  Returns:
      The organization ID (string) or None if not found or an error occurs.
  """

  # Use v1beta1 version only this version currently supports filtering by domain
  try:
    service = build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1beta1', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
    filter_str = f"domain:{organization_name}"  # Search by display name
    request = service.organizations().list(filter=filter_str)
    response=request.execute()
    organizations = response.get('organizations', [])
  except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error listing organizations: {e}")
    return None

  # Check if any organization was found with the provided name
  if not organizations:
    print(f"Organization with name '{organization_name}' not found!")
    return None

  # Assuming unique names, return the first organization's ID
  return organizations[0]['organizationId']

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import google.auth
  import sys

  # Retrieve credentials (assuming gcloud auth is configured)
  credentials, _ = google.auth.default()

  # Get organization name from command line argument (assuming 1st argument)
  if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print(f"Usage: python {sys.argv[0]} <organization_name>")
    sys.exit(1)
  organization_name = sys.argv[1]

  # Get and print organization ID (or handle error)
  organization_id = get_org_id_from_name(credentials, organization_name)
  if organization_id:
    print(f"Organization ID for '{organization_name}': {organization_id}")
  else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve organization ID.")

